# how can I change the order of rows of a matrix in a predefined order?

Tags: matrix

I am  wondering how I can change the order of rows of a matrix in a predefined manner?

let's say i have a matrix a=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8] 
and i have a vector b=[3 1 4 2]

can I change the order of a according to b?

to get: 
a_rearranged= [5 6; 1 2; 7 8; 3 4]

I tryed to use the sort command, but it only gives me the alteratives of sorting in mode descending and ascending

Thank you so much for any help!
Lena

Comment: Add more tags. What language? Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can just index an array with another array.

```
a_rearranged = a(b)
```

*assuming you're using Matlab. a[b] in Python but that would require your indices start at 0.